# How to revive a defunct chat room?

Tags: discussion, status-completed

https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/64193/2017/8/21

I came across @Tonepoet's this defunct chatroom that has been "automatically deleted for inactivity."

Since it is an interesting topic I should like to see it revived.

How is that done here on ELU?

Note 2: the chat section warns users not to create duplicate rooms.  But if such a defunct room cannot be revived is it possible to create a new room to feature the same topic?

Comment: Do not bother trying to ping somebody if they never participated in a post, because It simply does not work. If you are curious as to how I found this irrespective of that, then I just happened to be around meta anyway. I know moderators can unlock chats, but I'm not sure if they can undelete them. If it was deleted, it *probably* didn't have much of interest in it anyway. I'm not sure, but I would not  suppose that it would make much sense for deleted chats count as duplicates. How did you even find that anyway, and what was its topic? I do not have the U.R.L. memorized.

Comment: It was not an attempt to ping you, @Tonepoet, but simply a style of referring to SE members within posts. This is your chat room topic: Vocabulary Size Estimation: A Room for Objectively Establishing the Size of your Vocabulary https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/64193/2017/8/21 I found it listed but 'automatically deleted for inactivity' while going through a list of chatrooms on ELU Chat: https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=english.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3):

I've undeleted the room. If there's some other way I can help, feel free to ping me in EL&U chat.

Comment: Thanks a lot @MetaEd! It's meant to encourage users to check out their vocabulary. It can be very revealing to oneself to know which words are assumed to be 'known words' but their meanings are not conclusively known in our own mind. The test also shows us a number of rare words which we might be motivated to look up in the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Moderators can delete/undelete rooms. Feel free to ask a moderator. Some moderators are frequently seen in the chat rooms. Asking on meta works too.

Comment: Thanks for the information @NVZ!